# Insert query neither executed or neither gives exception

Tags: java, mysql, scala

Is it possible that i run a `mysql` `insert  query` and it doesn't give any `exception` , and still it doesn't entry to my sql.
*and the query is ok*.

if still it happens then what are the conditions when this can be happen?

Comment: statement.executeUpdate() returns int . Check value of int. If int is 0 then query is executed but insert is not happened.  It may also happened that autocommit is false. in that case you have to commit to take effect in database.

Comment: First try your statement by hand in MySQL client. Then indicate how/which code is using `executeUpdate` (direct JDBC, Anorm, Slick,  ...).

Answer (score 2):

I have two suggestions for you.

Is you autocommit flag is false ?  If yes then you have to call `commit()` on connection for insert to take effect in databse.

Check `int` value returned by executeUpdate() to ensure that insert has been successful or not.

you can also check warning by calling `getWarnings()` on statement.